# The easiest way to make a Canvas Background (with DrawingBrush) mouse interactive?

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas

I am using the Canvas Background as a writing pad. I would like to attach
a PreviewMouseMove event in a behavior when the cursor is moved into, in, or out of the canvas. Something like:

```
canvas.PreviewMouseMove += Canvas_PreviewMouseMove;
```

Ofcource, the Canvas.Background is a brush and so I am (currently) using a Drawing brush to define the geometries as:

```
XAML:
 <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" >
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"  ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                            <DrawingBrush.Viewport>
                                <MultiBinding>
                                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                        <conv:RectConverter/>
                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                    <Binding Path="DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.ViewPortWidth"/>
                                    <Binding Path="DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.ViewPortHeight"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </DrawingBrush.Viewport>
                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                        <GeometryDrawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Purple" Opacity="0.2" />
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="LightGreen"/>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                <RectangleGeometry>
                                                    <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                                        <MultiBinding>
                                                            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                                <conv:DrawingBoxConverter/>
                                                            </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                            <Binding Path="DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.DrawingBoxTop"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.ViewPortWidth"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.DrawingBoxHeight"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                                </RectangleGeometry>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                <GeometryGroup>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="{Binding DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.EndPointHeight}"/>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="{Binding DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.EndPointWidth}"/>
                                                </GeometryGroup>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Green"/>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                <GeometryGroup>
                                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="{Binding DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.StartPointMidline}" 
                                                                  EndPoint="{Binding DrawingLayer.MainCanvas.EndPointMidline}"/>
                                                </GeometryGroup>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Red">
                                                    <Pen.DashStyle>
                                                        <DashStyle Dashes="4,12"/>
                                                    </Pen.DashStyle>
                                                    </Pen>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        </DrawingBrush>
                    </Canvas.Background>
```

This produces the nice background:

[image]

But how now do I allow for the mouse events of PreviewMouseMove? All solutions that I've found state to make the background transparent. So should I not put the pad in the background? And if not in the background, how does this work with the Viewport? (I've read where using Path.Data would solve the issue, but then I do not know how to combine Path.Data with a viewport).

Could a Border element (in some form) be used in the XAML to solve the issue?

Ultimately, all I am trying to achieve is a clean pad (using a canvas) that responds to mouse enter, mouse move, and mouse leave events. (It shouldn't be this much of a problem).

Any help or suggestions is most appreciated.

Note: I do NOT need to interact with the geometries, only know the location of the cursor when it is inside the canvas.

TIA.

Edit#1. (Please excuse the wall of code). Here is the RectConverter:

```
 public class RectConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new Rect(0d, 0d, (double)values[0], (double)values[1]);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please provide the converters DrawingBoxConverter/RectConverter.

Comment: The PreviewMouseMove should get fired provided that you have set the Background property of the Canvas to *any* Brush including a DrawingBrush. So what is your issue here?

Comment: @mm8 That's what I thought...but no mouse events are being called (which is the basic problem here). I'm thinking it might have something to do with the Geometries??

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible sample of your issue if you need any further help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve